# iPhone Camera - Choose from Library or Take Photo

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

Please look at the image below !!

[image]

So in this image... You can see a pop-up from the bottom which gives the user 3 options when he 'taps' the 'Camera' button.

What is that view ? Is it a modal view controller which gets dismissed when an option is selected ?

**Edit:**

**So it is UIActionSheet** ! I have one more question on this, but StackOverflow would love it if I could edit the question rather than putting up a new one.

So yes.. The option "Take Photo" uses the UIImagePickerController, and the "Cancel" button is the resignFirstResponder... What about "Choose From Library" ? How do I access the photos in the iphone photo library ? Any sample code ?

Thanks !

Comment: This helps !! http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/iphone/9781449394004/chapter-4/53#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODE0NDkzOTQwMDQvNTQ=

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to edit in this case. It's more helpful for future visitors for there to be a single question and answer. That  said, you'll want to use a `UIImagePickerController` for both. I've found the documentation to be pretty clear, but you can always search StackOverflow if you encounter problems. It's a common question.

Answer (score 5):

This is standard [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) control

**Edit:** Images from library can also be accessed using `UIImagePickerController`. For that you need to set picker's sourceType proprety to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` (Check class reference for more details and for all sourceType values)