# PhoneGap: invoke UIImagePickerController

Tags: xcode, cordova, uiimagepickercontroller

How can this be done with Phonegap? Is this even possible?

See this post for an image of what I'm looking for:

[iPhone Camera - Choose from Library or Take Photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611598/iphone-camera-choose-from-library-or-take-photo)

EDIT:

There's a plugin for this

https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/NativeControls

Answer (score 0):

This is something I have achieved by using Sencha-Touch

See the demo [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/) (User Interface > Overlays > Action Sheet)

See the API : http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.ActionSheet

[EDIT]

You can also use this PhoneGap plugin :

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ActionSheet